# Plotting a large matrix into a pixel matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I am calculating navigation measure into a matrix from pigeon tracks.  The output will look like data frame made by the example code below.  Each row is a different window length while each column is the number of seconds since release. Data range is between 0 for no data, 0.001 to 1 for data.

What I want too do is plot each point as a non overlapping square on a XY plot, along a colour scale. So 0 = white (no data) while, 0.001-0.1 is dark blue, 0.101-.2 is light blue etc. Is there a plot method which will do this?

```
example.data<-c(0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,1.000,0.000,0.000, 0.000,0.000,1.000,0.956,0.000,0.000,0.000,1.000,0.991,0.948,0.000,0.000,1.000,0.989,0.985,0.944,0.000,1.000,0.998,0.993,0.989,0.954,1.000,0.995,0.100,4.000,0.990,1.000,0.987,0.500,0.600,0.986,1.000,0.993,0.450,0.200,0.250)

example.data<-as.matrix(example.data[1:5,1:9] )

names(example.data<)<-paste("Seconds",c(1:9))
row.names(example.data<)<- paste("Window",c(1:5))
```

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Comment: I use the `image()` function for this... But ggplot2 can do it as well. Do you have a preference?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am using quilt.plot() and have adjusted my output to a dataframe with xy coordinates. It seems to be working, now I just have to work out how to not have an automatic scale.  Cheers all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the plot `heatmap`. You need a numeric matrix

```
x <- as.matrix(example.data)
heatmap(x[1:10,1:10],Rowv=NA,Colv=NA,reorderfun=NA,hclustfun=NA)
```

But if you try and plot all that data you get a multicolour mess that doesn't really say anything.

Comment: Awesome, the example data is an unordered mess but the real data changes in steps so it will look more ordered with large patches of blue and red.

Comment: The heat map plot looks promising but the pattern does not look like what I should get from the example data. For instance the bottom line should be all one colour e.g. red, while the first cell on line two should be one colour (e.g. white), first two on line three should be that same colour and so on.

Comment: hmm yeah, it must be doing something. The output for your new example data when I run heatmap looks similar to the output from beroe's image but transposed. Looks like image is more what you were after

Comment: I think either Jeremy's method or mine will do what you want — you might have to transpose or sometimes flip the matrix and set up the color map manually. Some functions use `0,0` as the upper left and others use it as the lower left.

Answer (score 2):

You can reshape to a matrix (using `matrix` instead of `as.matrix`) and then visualize with `image()`. I added one value to your data set so it is 5x9 instead of 44 elements long...

```
numrows = 5
numcols = 9
example.matrix = matrix(example.data,numrows,numcols)
image(example.matrix,col=blue9)
```

Output:

[image]